# Catalog rows according to type conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a given dataFrame with four columns -

| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 1 | 3.2 | 4.2 | 1 |
| 1.9 | 1.2 | 5.4 | 3 |

I want to add a new column by this condition - if X1 and X4 are integers - so 1, else 0 as "bug".

I try this:

```py
x = []
for column in df:
        if isinstance(df['T1'][i], int) == True and isinstance(df['T4'][i], int) == True:
            x.append(0)     
        else: 
            x.append(1)
```

Output:

| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | bug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3.2 | 4.2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1.9 | 1.2 | 5.4 | 3 | 1 |

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Show the exact output you expect, for the sample input you show.

Comment: I added an example :)

Comment: And what actually happens when you run? Does x contain `[0, 1, 0, 1]` after running? What does it contain? The result should give you a clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: All the rows marked as "1" - thrown to the "else"

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if isinstance(x['X1'],int) and isinstance(x['X4'],int) else 'bug', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! But all the columns were marked as "bug"

Comment: Are you sure your data in the datafram is an integer and not a float?

Comment: Yes... I also try to change the "int" to "float" but it's still marked all the rows as "bug"